# getting identity value from database using promises

Tags: javascript, vue.js, promise, axios

I'm pretty new to the world of promises, axios and the node-mssql world.  So I'm probably doing this wrong.

I have a vue.js application where I'm trying to insert a record into the table.  I was hoping to use promises to get the value of the identity value of the insert I just performed.

The insert part is working, but getting it back and using it, is not.

Here is my calling code which is wrapped in a Try/Catch (error below):

```
            var addFamilyMemberRowObj;

            axios
              .get("http://localhost:5000/addMember?familyId="+ vm.familyId+"&memberName="+vm.memberName+"&isAdmin="+vm.isParent)
              .then(response => (vm.returnId = response.data))
              .then(console.log(vm.returnId["Data"][0].id))
              .then(vm.memberId =  vm.returnId["Data"][0].id)
               .then(
                 addFamilyMemberRowObj = {
                  arrIndex: vm.addFamilyRowIndex,
                  familyId: vm.familyId,
                  familyName: vm.familyName,
                  familyMemberName: vm.memberName,
                  memberId: vm.memberId,
                  isParent: vm.isParent
                }
              )
              .then(vm.addFamilyRowArray.push(addFamilyMemberRowObj))
              .then(vm.addFamilyRowIndex = vm.addFamilyRowIndex + 1);
```

Some items you may need to know.  returnId is an array.  I'll show you my DB code below.  the `vm.returnId["Data"][0].id` is the only way that I can see to get the value.

I have printed this value out, outside of the promise and it does eventually return a value.  Which leads me to believe it might be a timing issue.

My database code is as follows:

```
app.get('/addMember', function(req,res){
    var data = {
              "Data":""
      };

      try 
      {
          const pool7 = new sql2.ConnectionPool(config, err => {
              pool7.request()
              .query("INSERT INTO Member (FamilyId, MemberName, isAdmin)VALUES("+ req.query.familyId +",'" + req.query.memberName + "', '" + req.query.isAdmin + "') SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY() as id", (err, result) => {
                  data["Data"] = result.recordset;
                  console.log(data);

                  res.json(data);
              })
          })

      } catch (err) {
          console.log("hasLogin: " + err)
      }     
});
```

After this is called, I have verified that the insert is working (and the console.log is also printing out the correct value [from this code]):

> { Data: [ { id: 24 } ] }

When I look at the console.log from the vue code I get the following message:

> "Unable to get property '0' of undefined or null reference"

However, as I mentioned if I print out `vm.returnId["Data"][0].id` outside of the promise I eventually get a value on the subsequent calls (the id is 1 behind).

I know that the syntax is correct as far as getting the value, but inside the promise it doesn't like it.

I know that this is a lot to unpack.  I'm probably doing many things wrong.  As you can tell, a lot of these code snippets are straight from the samples.  Any help would be welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The root of the problem is that `then` expects a function as an argument.
`.then(console.log(vm.returnId["Data"][0].id))` is an incorrect call.

It should be `.then(() => console.log(vm.returnId["Data"][0].id))`

Comment: That appeared to solve the id issue.  Would I have to do this for all .then calls?  Specifically this one:                  .then(() =>(
                      addFamilyMemberRowObj = {
                      arrIndex: vm.addFamilyRowIndex,
                      familyId: vm.familyId,
                      familyName: vm.familyName,
                      familyMemberName: vm.memberName,
                      memberId: vm.memberId,
                      isParent: vm.isParent}
                      ))

Comment: Yes, you have to alter all of them. `.then` executes a function that passed to it when Promise is resolved. More on topic here:
https://devdocs.io/javascript/global_objects/promise/then
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises

Comment: Thank you for your answer and your follow-up links.  Very helpful!